# Jekyll: Define a new variable based on page variables

Tags: variables, jekyll

## My Problem

I am writing a static site in Jekyll. Each post should have a "Posted by" subtitle with the author's name, with an optional link to their webpage, and a fallback to the site title if no author name is defined.

For example, suppose that my site title is "Acme corp".

### Author and "URL

```
author: Someone
author_url: https://their_site.com
```

Should give `[Someone](https://their_site.com)`

### Author

```
author: Someone
```

Should give `Someone`.

### No Author

Should give `Acme corp`.

## What have I tried

I can hard-code the logic into the `_layouts/post.html` page, but I will have to repeat myself in other page templates:

```html
<span class="meta">Posted by
{% if page.author_url %}
<a href="{{ page.author_url }}">
{% endif %}
{% if page.author %}{{ page.author }}{% else %}{{ site.title }}{% endif %}
{% if page.author_url %}
</a>
{% endif %}
on {{ page.date | date: "%B %-d, %Y" }}</span>
```

## My question

Is there a way to define a global variable (e.g. `author_html`) based on the values of `page.author` and `page.author_url`, that will be accessible on all template pages?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you make an `author.html` include and call the include with the current author (or fallback on your default) in an parameter, like:

```
{% capture author_link %}
  {% if page.author_url %}
  <a href="{{ page.author_url }}">
  {% endif %}
  {% if page.author %}{{ page.author }}{% else %}{{ site.title }}{% endif %}
  {% if page.author_url %}
  </a>
  {% endif %}
{% endcapture %}
{% include author.html author=author_link %}
```

In the include you get the author by calling `include.author`. For further information see the [jekyll-docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/) on includes. 
I hope this solves your problem.